# Does combining two standardized test results to a standardized test?

Tags: definition

Let's say I have two standardized tests, test A and test B. If I combine the two tests (no items will be discarded, all will be included) to make test C. Can we say test C will be also a standardized test?

Answer (score 0):

No. Standardized tests are considered standardized because they were administered to a normative sample. You would only consider test C a standardized test if it is administered to its own normative sample and scores were created for test C based upon the scores generated from the sample. There are also administration procedures for test C that should be in place to ensure that the test was administered to the normative sample in the same manner across examiners and examinees.